# Haskell - replace case with guards

Tags: haskell

i'd like to know if in this portion of code is possible to replace the case statement with guards:

```
firstFunction  :: String -> Maybe MyType
secondFunction :: MyType -> Integer
myFunction     :: String -> Maybe Integer
myFunction xs = case firstFunction xs of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just x  -> Just( secondFunction x )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need a guard, just `fmap`: `fmap secondFunction (firstFunction x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [*pattern guard* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard), like:

```
myFunction :: String -> Maybe Integer
myFunction xs | Just x <- firstFunction xs = Just (secondFunction x)
              | otherwise = Nothing
```

But what you here do is basically "`fmap`" the result of `firstFunction`, like:

```
myFunction :: String -> Maybe Integer
myFunction xs = fmap secondFunction (firstFunction xs)
```

`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is used to "map" over a functor. Now `Maybe` is a functor, [defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-836):

> ```
> instance Functor Maybe  where
>     fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
>     fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
> ```

which is basically the logic you wrote here.