# Replace where case of with guards

Tags: haskell

I have specific situation I've checked a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351881/haskell-replace-case-with-guards) and I was wondering if the same strategy could be applied within a where statement in haskell.

Suppose I have a function:

```
Func1:: Term -> [Term]
Func1 (Foo a b) = [ Foo a' b | a' <- Func1a ] ++ [ Foo b' a | b' <- Func1b ] ++ M
   where
   M = case a of
      Bar v body -> [substitute var b body]
      _               -> []
```

Is there a way to replace the case of with guards?

Comment: I think you want to write `func1`, `func1a`, `func1b` and `m` in lowercase otherwise they will be seen as constructors which will cause many errors when compiling. And I think `var` should be `v` on the fifth line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```hs
func1 :: Term -> [Term]
func1 (Foo a b) = [ Foo a' b | a' <- func1a ] ++ [ Foo b' a | b' <- func1b ] ++ m
  where
    m | Bar v body <- a = [substitute v b body]
      | otherwise       = []
```

I think the main point of confusion might be that you can place the `|` immediately after `m`. The rest it is very similar to the answer that you already linked.

Comment: I've tried to use the snippet but I'm getting `Variable not in scope: b:: Term`

Comment: @gaming4mining I am able to compile this code. Are you sure you have indented it correctly? Can you send a link to your whole file on pastebin or something like that?